# Ubuntu 14.04, wanted to upgrade to 16.04

Tags: updates, ubuntu

I have elementary the freya 0.3.2, based on ubuntu 14.04, wanted to upgrade to 16.04.
I've tried to update but it gives me an error, which is as follows:

An update from 'freya' to 'xenial' is not supported with this tool.

I appreciate your help solving the problem.
Thank you.

Comment: You need to make a clean install. **[What is the recommended way to upgrade elementary OS 0.3 Freya to 0.4 Loki?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7502/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-upgrade-elementary-os-0-3-freya-to-0-4-loki)**

Answer (score 1):

You can't upgrade from Freya to Loki. You have to perform a fresh install.